# How do I stream video with multi camera adapter from python on RPI to JS/HTML interface on laptop?

Tags: javascript, python, html, websocket, raspberry-pi

For a project at university we have to build a Remotely Operating Vehicle. Among other things this vehicle needs to be able to identify suspicious objects. We use the RPI4 to control our ROV and we've bought a multi camera adapter and 2 rpi cameras to identify the objects. We've managed to get the both cameras working at the same time, but now we want to stream them to a website.

The RPI is used as an hotspot and via python (with websockets) it sends data to an interface on my laptop (HTML, JS, CSS). I've used python and C++ before to get both cameras working on the RPI, but I want to stream the recording to my laptop now. How do I do this? Via python with websockets or are there different options? I've never done this before so I don't know if there are better solutions for this.

Answer (score 1):

With motion you can easily stream 2 cameras from the raspberry pi. If you are interested have a look at this:

> [single Camera
> stream](https://strobelstefan.org/2018/02/11/raspberry-pi-und-motion/)
>
> [multiple Camera
> stream](https://strobelstefan.org/2016/02/08/motion-mit-mehreren-kameras/)

To simply view the network streams you can enter the Ip-address of your pi (with the correct ports in case of multiple camera system) into your browser.

If you want to import the network streams into a python programm i recommend PyQT5. To import a video stream into a GUI have a look at this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiWgdHAB5kc&ab_channel=SuperCoders).

For communication between Laptop and Raspberry-Pi, websockets are a good choice for my experience.